# $.get with dynamic data names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having an issue trying to set the data name or the objects being passed in. I am writing a system that uses AJAX to send requests to the server which then returns the necessary data. However, I am trying to make things generic to where if the developer adds more "slates" then it will automatically send the request on its behalf. The code looks as following:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".slate").each(function(){

               $.get("requests.php", { $(this).attr('name') : "true" }, function(data){

               }); 
           }); 
        });
```

in other words it takes the name of the element and applies it to the query string. JavaScript doesn't seem to like the

```
        $(this).attr('name')
```

in the syntax which is understandable since it expects just text (not a var or a string). Is there a way to make this work? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This should work. What errors do you get?

Comment: "Missing : after property id". I am using Netbeans as the IDE and it is underlining the code is nice bold red. If I change this to the normal form (say, thisData) then it has no problem with it.

Comment: Have you tried running this code? I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not an Expert, but in javascript you can access an array (or object) in this way: myarray[$(this).attr('name')] why don't you build the object first and then add it the index in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".slate").each(function(){
           var data = {};
           data[$(this).attr('name')] = "true";
           $.get("requests.php", data, function(data){

           }); 
       }); 
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't this code does exactly the same thing as @user1260028's code but in a more verbose manner?

Comment: You'll get a syntax error with the op code, after the `$` http://jsfiddle.net/LKRDN/

Comment: Hah! Wonderful. @Blender while I understand that the old way might of worked, the issue is that if the IDE doesn't accept the current syntax, the IDE features wont work properly until I fix the complaint.

Comment: AFAICT, neither Node.js nor SpiderMonkey (in Firefox) will accept an expression (other than a simple string literal) as a label in object-literal notation.